# Im trying to run old code, which I know works, and am getting some new errors

Tags: java

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 > -4
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3781)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3741)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:427)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Anyone know why this could happen

For reference I am trying to run a JavaFX project from 2019
I didnt make any changes to the code and it isn't working now

Comment: Yeah but I never used the method Arrays.copyOfRange in my code

Comment: And @OHGODSPIDERS by me saying the code used to work before is because maybe JAVAFX has changed or opens the possibility my code is outdated

Comment: Also i checked through my code and I don't even use arrays in it, I prefer arraylists

Comment: Okay, So the stacktrace doesn't even mention any part of your code? Do I understand that correct?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't mention anything in the code, which is why im so confused

Comment: Hm, looking at https://code.yawk.at/java/13/jdk.compiler/com/sun/tools/javac/launcher/Main.java#com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main%23execute%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Ccom.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.Context%29 it looks to me like the problem is that an `InvocationTargetException` is thrown and before that gets passed higher/rethrown the code tries to modify its stacktrace where the Arrays.copyOfRange method is used and the above runtime exception happens. Unfortunately this looks like the original `InvocationTargetException` is swallowed and the original error msg is lost